# Tried to manually upgrade Python from 2.7.3 to 2.7.13 but now system broken

Tags: python, pip, upgrade

Downloaded the source tarball and install it the way it was mentioned using `./configure --prefix=/usr/local` followed by `make altinstall`

And it failed at the `libinstall` stage where in I just renamed my existing directories at `/usr/local/lib/python2.7` and `/usr/lib/python2.7` and then retried. This time it worked

However after that I've had a hard time running python. When I try invoking python I see this

```
ImportError: No module named site
```

Upon doing some investigation, I stumbled upon [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/905372/could-not-find-platform-independent-libraries-prefix) but it doesn't help. Is there a way to fix this? Or if it too clunky a thing to fix, can I just revert? If yes how? I didn't delete anything but merely renamed the existing directories as mentioned earlier

Comment: Uninstall python and reinstall it from scratch? I believe for minor updates (2.x.y to 2.x.z) you can `pip install --upgrade python`

Comment: That didn't work for me. Had that worked, I'd have gone that route only